# Detect the Time when user stop interacting with the screen in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget, gesture

I want to make a timer when the user stops interacting with the screen (The user unTouched the mobile screen).

I Tried Listner Widget to Detect User Action on parent Widget of screen
and I didn't work

```
//1
    Listener(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onPointerDown: (e) => print('listener'),
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => print('raisedButton'),
      ), ),
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: I updated the question with widgets i tried , I want to detect when user stop interact or stop touching the screen

Comment: see [addGlobalRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerRouter/addGlobalRoute.html)